# is my Lid Switch broken? [Debian]

Tags: debian, systemd, backlight, dist-upgrade

yesterday, on a ThinkPad Edge E520-1143B laptop, I did an upgrade from Debian 9 (Stretch) to Debian 10 (Buster) following these two guides:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-9-stretch-to-debian-10-buster

The upgrade finished but I now encounter some unexpected behavior...

The Debian 9 system was working like a charm. One of its charms was a simple "just turn the screen off when the lid is closed". This is not working any more...

I remember being prompted during the upgrade if I wanted to keep the personalized `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` or get the one of the developer. I chose to keep the personalized one hoping to have the Lid Switch working as before.

So, how can I get this feature back?

this is my actual `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
HandlePowerKey=ignore
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

I have tried commenting and uncommenting the lines and doing `# systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` but the lid switch seems to do nothing.

`# udevadm monitor` leaves an empty output when I close and open the lid. (may be this is the wrong way to monitor the Lid Switch?)

From `# cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1
```

I installed `libinput-tools` to run `libinput debug-events`. The output doesn't log any Lid-Switch-event..

I know I can fix this with a clean install, but this is not the way I want to go for now.